# Looking for a book about a human-nature predicting supercomputer

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for the name of a book (might be a short story) which I have read many years ago. The general plot as I remember it:

- There is a supercomputer which can predict with good accuracy the human actions in the next several days (after that, it is just less accurate).
- The computer could alert the police of future possible crimes, and would.
- The computer alerted the police that a man is going to commit a murder, and the man is placed under arrest.
- His son goes to a computer-interface station to ask the computer for help.
- The computer sends the son on a complicated quest.

**Spoiler alert**: I am giving away plot-sensitive details at the end, so they're hidden below.

> - The son kills the computer, and we find out that the murder-alert was actually on the son (but their system automatically redirects it to the parent's name, or just a wrong identification for Mr. Surname).
>  - We find out the computer planned the whole thing, because it got depressed after dealing with the pain and suffering of the whole human race.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_the_Troubles_of_the_World):

> "***All the Troubles of the World***" is a science fiction short story by Isaac Asimov. The story first appeared in the April 1958 issue of Super-Science Fiction, and was reprinted in the 1959 collection Nine Tomorrows. It is one of a loosely-connected series of stories by Asimov concerning the fictional supercomputer Multivac.

The story synopsys matches your description to a T, including the end.

> To confirm his suspicion, Othman asks Multivac a question never previously posed to the vast computer, "Multivac, what do you yourself want more than anything else?". Multivac's answer is succinct and unequivocal: "I want to die."

Comment: Yes! Yes, it is! I thought I went over all the Asimov stories in Wikipedia, turns out I missed some :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -3):

You might also consider "When Harlie was One" by Gerrold.

Comment: Given that the OP has already identified the story, can you give some insight into why you think this deserves their attention?